# why git svn clone failed when using cygwin?

Tags: git, svn, version-control, cygwin, git-svn

```
 git svn clone https://192.168.11.115/svn/xx/test/
Initialized empty Git repository in /cygdrive/d/xx/test/.git/
Can't load '/usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.14/i686-cygwin-threads-64int/auto/SVN/_Core/_Core.dll' for module SVN::_Core: No such file or directory at /usr/lib/perl5/5.14/i686-cygwin-threads-64int/DynaLoader.pm line 190.
 at /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.14/i686-cygwin-threads-64int/SVN/Base.pm line 59
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.14/i686-cygwin-threads-64int/SVN/Core.pm line 5.
Compilation failed in require at /usr/lib/git-core/git-svn line 41.
```

it is confusing...

Answer (score 2):

It might be because, as in [this thread](http://cygwin.com/ml/cygwin/2009-12/msg00511.html), you don't have sqlite3 installed.

```
$ cygcheck -l libsqlite3_0
/usr/bin/cygsqlite3-0.dll
```

> > I'm not sure why this is missing from your system.
> >     `subversion-perl` depends on subversion which depends on `libsqlite3_0`.
>
> `libsqlite3_0` does not install any dll, `sqlite3` package installs the dll.
>   This also fixes the svn problem someone else reported.

Comment: `SVN::_Core: No such file or directory at /usr/lib/perl5/5.14/i686-cygwin-threads-64int/DynaLoader.pm line 190` i don't think this error have something to do with sqlite ...

Comment: @hugemeow it is just a side-effect of some missing dynamic libs. My point is that said missing libs might be from sqlite3.

Comment: @garyp that could be the base for another question, then, and I would be interested in its answer.

Answer (score 2):

I think the version of your subversion-perl package does not match the version of your subversion package.

I had the same issue because I was using subversion 1.7 and git-svn installed subversion-perl 1.8 as a dependency. Downgrading subversion-perl to 1.7 fixed that.